# Issues with very tall web pages on Safari 6+ and Mobile Browsers

Tags: html, css, performance, mobile, webkit

### The very tall web page

My web app displays "documents" as a vertical sequence of images.

Every image represents a page of the document.

Images are **not** loaded at startup, instead they are lazy-loaded:

- for every page a placeholder of the same size (an empty div with a gray background and specified size) is placed into the DOM at startup (at document ready, with a JavaScript routine);
- when a page enters the viewport (and stays inside for at least 0.25 seconds) it's image is loaded from the server over the placeholder;

Basically I've implemented the basic behaviour of most desktop Readers like Preview or Acrobat Reader: the user browses a document scrolling up/down the content of the window.

Some documents have lot of pages (300 or more), every page is about 850px tall: as the 300+ gray placeholders are injected into the DOM...

**the web page may become several thousands pixels tall**

When I started my project (about one year ago) considered this a *borderline* condition for browsers: web pages are not meant to be 240.000px tall! So I made tests (I was targeting desktop browser initially).

**Surprisingly the** `very-tall-web-page` **was not an issue at all!** All the browsers (IE8 included) didn't suffer at all. In fact the JavaScript was light, the DOM contained a reasonable number of nodes and -although the "logical" size of the page was huge- the browsers were smart enought to render only what needed to be displayed onscreen.

### Safari 6 and Safari 7

`very-tall-web-page` became an issue.

It seems the browser is attempting to render the whole web page (!) in **ram**: this involves using a lot of cpu, a lot of ram and a lot of time (browser is poorly responsive, scrolling and resizing hangs often).

If I remove the gray placeholders, the fixed background pattern I added, everything... and leave nothing but a long, white, empty web page nothing changes.

If I trigger **graphic-acceleration** applying `-webkit-transform: translatez(0);` to the `body` Safari becomes responsive again on window resizing and scrolling (as long I stay on the topmost part of the web page). But if I go down to the middle/bottom then scrolling hangs again and the page takes several seconds to update.

At least, once the page is redrawn, resizing remains responsive.

### Mobile Browsers

Since the beginning `very-tall-web-page` was an issue on iPad and mobile devices.

Mobile Safari was running out of memory and crashing with just 10-15 page-images documents.

Triggering **graphic-acceleration** solved again partially the problem.

No crash but if I scroll down too much it hangs for some time and is unable to render the page (it stays white).

### **Questions**

Is there anything I can make the `very-tall-web-page` work on Safari 6 / 7?

Is there any trick I can do to let it run on Mobile browsers?

Is the `very-tall-web-page` something that should be avoided anyway even when targeting desktop browsers?

### **--EDIT--**

The issue was fixed on Safari (Desktop) on version **7.1**